# ons-back-button onClick stoppropagation

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui

I'm using ons-navigator and want to override the function of a  on some point. I'm using the onClick handler which fires correctly.

However: after returning from the onClick handler, the navigator page is still popped. How to stop this?

I've already tried stopPropagation() and preventDefault() with no result.

Answer (score 0):

documentation says there is a cancel() method on prepush or prepop event that cancels the operation. usage is like

```
myNavigator.addEventListener('prepush', function(event) {
  if (needsCancel) {
     event.cancel(); // Cancel the operation
  }
});
```